# Bootstrap modal to confirm table row delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new to web work and I hope I can get some helpful answers here.  I am Using bootstraps framework to design a site and I am running into a small issue.  I have a table that has a delete button in the last cell and I would like for the button to delete the entire row. I would like for the delete button to activate a bootstrap modal to confirm the table rows deletion before it is deleted. Basically a warning that you are about to delete the entry yes or no.  The yes button obviously would delete the row.  Here is what I have so far.

HTML----

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Content 1</th>
        <th>View</th>
        <th>Content 2</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Edit / View / Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<!-- start: Table Body -->
<tbody>
    <tr class="btnDelete" data-id="1">
        <td>Content1</td>
        <td><a href="#">View</a>
        </td>
        <td>Content2</td>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td>
            <button id="btnDelete" href="">delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="btnDelete" data-id="2">
        <td>Content3</td>
        <td><a href="#">View</a>
        </td>
        <td>Content4</td>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td>
            <button id="btnDelete" href="">delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
 <!--/table-collapse -->
 <!-- start: Delete Coupon Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
             <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Warning!</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
             <h4> Are you sure you want to DELETE?</h4>

        </div>
        <!--/modal-body-collapse -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnDelteYes" href="#">Yes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        </div>
        <!--/modal-footer-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->
```

JS----

```
      $('#myModal').on('show', function () {
      var id = $(this).data('id'),
          removeBtn = $(this).find('.danger');
  })
   $('#btnDelete').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      $('#myModal').data('id', id).modal('show');
  });
  $('.btnDelteYes').click(function () {
      // handle deletion here
      var id = $('#myModal').data('id');
      $('[data-id=' + id + ']').remove();
      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  });
```

Obviously I am using the bootstrap css etc.

I hope I have given enough info to help solve my issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbash/Se52D/4/):

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: I checked it out but the delete isn't working so I think I understand your problem. There are a few things I would do differently. First off the modal hide can be done separately by using bootstrap's data-dismiss, Can't actually identify which row you're trying to remove so that needs to be defined so you can identify and remove the TR with Javascript.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have a few things wrong:

### Problem 1

An id attribute must be unique, it is used twice in your example.

```
<button id="btnDelete" href="">delete</button>
<button id="btnDelete" href="">delete</button>
```

---

### Problem 2

You do not need this code at all, however if you need it in the future use `.on('show.bs.modal', func...)`

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id'),
        removeBtn = $(this).find('.danger');
});
```

---

### Problem 3

`$(this)` here refers to the `btnDelete` button, which does not have a data-id attribute, the `data-id` is set on your `tr`

```
$('#btnDelete').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#myModal').data('id', id).modal('show');
});
```

[**Working fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Se52D/5/) with above errors corrected.

Comment: @JasonBash No problem glad i could help, would you mind [marking as accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if this solved your problem.