# Modal dialog to confirm delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm following this ([Bootstrap modal to confirm table row delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161488/bootstrap-modal-to-confirm-table-row-delete)) but I'm not sure why, but the modal dialog is not appearing.

I'm looking to basically do the same thing, although my table is dynamically created by my jQuery code:

```
$("#guests_table > tbody:last").append(
    "<tr class='btnDelete' data-id='" + guest.guest_id + "'>"
    + "<td>" + guest.guest_first_name + "</td>"
    + "<td>" + guest.guest_last_name + "</td>"
    + "<td>" + guest.guest_email + "</td>"
    + "<td>" + "<a href='editguest.html?guestId=" + guest.guest_id + "&hostId=" + hostId + "&registryId=" + guest.registry_id + " '>"
    + "<img src='images/edit26.png' height='60%' width='60%'></a></td>"
    + "<td><button class='btnDelete' href=''>delete</button></td>"
    + "</tr>");
});
```

In the head of the HTML page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Modal dialog:

```
<!-- start: Delete Coupon Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Warning!</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4>Are you sure you want to DELETE?</h4>

            </div>
            <!--/modal-body-collapse -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnDelteYes" href="#">Yes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
            <!--/modal-footer-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Button calls in the JS page:

```
$('btn.btnDelete').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
    $('#myModal').data('id', id).modal('show');
});

$('#btnDelteYes').click(function () {
    var id = $('#myModal').data('id');
    $('[data-id=' + id + ']').remove();
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
});
```

On delete I have an API call to delete but I'm just struggling to get the dialog to even appear. Any idea why?

Thank you

Comment: Where so you bind click event to show modal dialog?

Comment: Apologies, accidentally omitted it. Edited main post

Comment: Make sure `$('btn.btnDelete').on('click'` code is after `$("#guests_table > tbody:last").append(` code.

Comment: It still doesn't appear... not too sure why

Comment: I've copied the code from the JSfiddle onto a new HTML page and put the JavaScript into a new JS file to rule out anything causing it not to work, but it just does not show at all, so it might be me...

Comment: Check the demo in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your CSS selector when you bind delete button click event. It should be `.btn.btnDelete`, note `.` in front or it.

```
$('.btn.btnDelete').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
    $('#myModal').data('id', id).modal('show');
});
```

Also make sure delete button has class `btn` for this to work:

```
<button class='btn btnDelete' href=''>delete</button>
<!--    add btn ^ class    -->
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/X2hybmfUXGlFlaoFX4Al?p=preview

Comment: The plunker demo works, but if I move the JS code to the script.js file, then nothing appear

Comment: Open console, check for errors. Compare my demo with your code, something is different.

Comment: your script.js file should be written after calling jquery.min.js

Comment: I have your demo working in a separate script file here: http://jsfiddle.net/4f915wow/2/ but cannot get it to work with me. It's weird that as soon as I put the JS code in another file, and reference it, it doesn't work

Comment: I didn't put the button events directly after the append() function, once I realised that, I moved it. It now works. Thank you :)